To prove Tangent to the circle and Radius are Orthogonal


Prove that without using Proof by Contradiction, Tangent to the Circle and Radius are Perpendicular


Here is my try:
Consider a circle with Centre $O$ and a Tangent drawn to it at the point $P$ shown below.
Now on the tangent line I picked two points $A$ and $B$ which are equidistant from $P$, that is $AP=PB$. Now I have joined $OA$ and $OB$. If we can prove $OA=OB$, We are done.
But any hints will be appreciated.


What is the Proof by Contradiction anyway?

@M.Riyan It means we assume a priori that $OP$ is not $\perp$ to $AB$ and proceed and arrive at a Contradiction.

If you have already proved that the shortest path from a point to a line lies on the perpendicular, then it's easy. But can that theorem be proved witout RAA? I don't think so. Otherwise you should resort to some analytical solution, but probably that's not what is wanted here.

Hint: $OP$ is perpendicular to the line $AB$ if and only if for any $X\ne P$ lying on $AB$, $OX>OP$, because $P$ is the perpendicular foot of $O$ on $AB$. Now think about what is the meaning of $OP$ to the circle.
